# Is creating your own question and then answering it allowed?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to ask a question you intend to answer immediately?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-you-intend-to-answer-immediately)

Is creating your own question and answer in order to provide a sort of how-to guide for something Sharepoint related allowed?

Comment: Yep, totally allowed and there is even a new feature for it: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: @KitMenke Wonderful, I know that existed globally as a feature, but a few SE sites are still evil about it :P  (and since i'm a slight rebel at heart, this is why i asked: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/36969/3732 since I see so many questions here about state machine workflows and they're using custom code or something, or referencing SPD but meaning VS2k10 or something :P)

Comment: Yeah I've seen that hostility before.. which is why I asked the original question here. :) Keep posting the good info!